# NodeJS - How do I detect other copies of my program?

Tags: node.js

I have written a NodeJS command-line program with two modes:

- mode foo: runs forever until the user presses Ctrl+C
- mode bar: runs once

If the user is already running the program in mode foo, then running it again in mode bar will cause errors. Thus, when the user invokes mode bar, I want to search for all other existing copies of my command-line program that are running and kill them (as a mechanism to prevent the errors before they happen).

Getting a list of processes in NodeJS is easy, but that doesn't help me much. If I simply kill all other node processes, then I might be killing other programs that are not mine. So, I need to know which specific node processes are the ones running my app. Is it even possible to interrogate a process to determine that information?

Another option is to have my program write a temporary file to disk, or write a value to the Windows registry, or something along those lines. And then, before my program exists, I could clean up the temporary value. However, this feels like a precarious solution, because if my program crashes, then the flag will never be unset and will remain orphaned forever.

What is the correct solution to this problem? How can I kill my own application?

Comment: This sounds like a typical use case for a PID file. The PID file should have a static name and location. If the process is killed forcefully, the file will be orphaned until the next time the program is executed. The program's pid can be found as `process.pid`

Comment: A PID file doesn't quite work, because there can be N running copies of my program.

Comment: You can get more detail about process like "CommandLine" of process to check what your own process, check more https://securityboulevard.com/2020/01/get-process-list-with-command-line-arguments/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using PowerShell:

```
import { execSync } from "child_process";

const CWD = process.cwd();

function validateOtherCopiesNotRunning(verbose: boolean) {
  if (process.platform !== "win32") {
    return;
  }

  // From: https://securityboulevard.com/2020/01/get-process-list-with-command-line-arguments/
  const stdout = execPowershell(
    "Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter \"name = 'node.exe'\" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CommandLine",
    verbose,
  );
  const lines = stdout.split("\r\n");
  const otherCopiesOfMyProgram= lines.filter(
    (line) =>
      line.includes("node.exe") &&
      line.includes("myProgram") &&
      // Exclude the current invocation that is doing a 1-time publish
      !line.includes("myProgram publish"),
  );
  if (otherCopiesOfMyProgram.length > 0) {
    throw new Error("You must close other copies of this program before publishing.");
  }
}

function execPowershell(
  command: string,
  verbose = false,
  cwd = CWD,
): string {
  if (verbose) {
    console.log(`Executing PowerShell command: ${command}`);
  }

  let stdout: string;
  try {
    const buffer = execSync(command, {
      shell: "powershell.exe",
      cwd,
    });
    stdout = buffer.toString().trim();
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to run PowerShell command "${command}":`, err);
  }

  if (verbose) {
    console.log(`Executed PowerShell command: ${command}`);
  }

  return stdout;
}
```